# Does ctags know about the type of a data member in a class?

Tags: ctags

I'm trying to learn about ctags in emacs.  I have built a TAGS file as per the instructions here: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags.  I think I'm using exuberent-ctags, but I'm not sure.

I have a large code base around statistical models.  Many classes have data members of the form

```
MySmartPointer<SomeModelType> model_;
```

This would be in a header file.  In the associated .cpp file I'll see code like

```
model_->do_something();
```

I'd like to press M-. and have emacs take me to the definition of `model_`.   Instead, I'm getting a long list of all the data members *everywhere* named model_, which is a very long list.

My questions are these:

1. Are my expectations realistic?  I.e does the ctags system contain enough information to know that the `model_` I'm clicking on belongs to the class whose member function I'm editing?
2. Is there an obvious configuration step that I have missed?  I create the TAGS file using ctags -e -R --extra=+a.  (I've tried with and without the --extra flag).
3. (Added later) If making TAGS work this way is hard, what should I be looking at instead?  I assume I'm not the first person to need this functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48414520 is likely of interest to you (and is quite recent).

Answer (score 1):

> Are my expectations realistic? I.e does the ctags system contain enough information to know that the model_ I'm clicking on belongs to the class whose member function I'm editing?

No, a TAGS file is just a list of names and where to find them.  If you have duplicate names, you need to specify which one you want.

i.e. TAGS are poorly-suited to object-oriented programming or other name-spacing techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Ctags by itself only list tag name, file path and line number.

But you can still use Emacs Lisp code to get more precise result (https://github.com/redguardtoo/counsel-etags):

- Use negative file path pattern to exclude some candidates *manually* through ivy's filter UI (`counsel-etags` uses `ivy`)
- Write lisp rules to exclude noise *automatically*. For example, find `model_`'s type in current file by search from top of the file to find `SomeModelType` and expect the class `SomeModelType` is defined in a file `SomeModelType.cpp`.
- When there are multiple candidates, sort the candidate using string distance algorithm. For example `do_something` is defined in both `ParentModelType.cpp` and `ParentViewType.cpp`, Candidate from `ParentModelType.cpp` is placed at the top because it's closer to `SomeModelType.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

At least, universal-ctags knows types of fields in C and C++ input. However, the TAGS file format doesn't allow ctags to record them. As a result, Emacs cannot do more.

```
[jet@localhost]/tmp% cat /tmp/foo.c
cat /tmp/foo.c
struct A {
  char member;
};

struct B {
  float member;
};
[jet@localhost]/tmp% u-ctags  --fields=+tZ -o - /tmp/foo.c 
u-ctags  --fields=+tZ -o - /tmp/foo.c 
A   /tmp/foo.c  /^struct A {$/;"    s   file:
B   /tmp/foo.c  /^struct B {$/;"    s   file:
member  /tmp/foo.c  /^  char member;$/;"    m   scope:struct:A  typeref:typename:char   file:
member  /tmp/foo.c  /^  float member;$/;"   m   scope:struct:B  typeref:typename:float  file:
```

See "typedef:" fields of output.